# Android Firebase phone authentication INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have followed all the steps to configure phone auth for Firebase but still, I am not able to get OTP from Firebase.

Is it mandatory to link play store account to Firebase for phone auth?

Comment: Didi u enable phone auth in firebase ??

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable Phone auth in firebase Authentication SIGN-IN METHOD.
2. Past this code in onCreate Method.

   ```
      mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

       @Override
       public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
           // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
           // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
           //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
           // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
           //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verificaiton without
           //     user action.
           Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);

           //signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
       }

       @Override
       public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
           // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
           // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.
           Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e);

           Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
               // Invalid request
               // ...
           } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
               // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
               // ...
           }

           // Show a message and update the UI
           // ...
       }

       @Override
       public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                              PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
           // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
           // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
           // by combining the code with a verification ID.
           Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verificationId);

           // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
           mVerificationId = verificationId;
           mResendToken = token;

           // ...
       }
   };
   ```

I turned off auto verification. User always have to input the code.

3. send code to user

   ```
   String phoneNumber = phoneNumberET.getText().toString();
   PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
           phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
           60,                 // Timeout duration
           TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
           this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
           mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
   ```
4. Take code from user and send it to verify

   ```
   String code = mCodeEt.getText().toString();
   PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, code);
   signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
   ```
5. This method is result method

   ```
   private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
   mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
           .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                   if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                       // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                       Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");

                       FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                       //Sucess do what u want to do
                       // [START_EXCLUDE]
                       //updateUI(STATE_SIGNIN_SUCCESS, user);
                       // [END_EXCLUDE]
                   } else {
                       // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                       Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                       if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                           // The verification code entered was invalid
                           // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                           mCodeEt.setError("Invalid code.");
                           // [END_EXCLUDE]
                       }
                       // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                       // Update UI
                       //updateUI(STATE_SIGNIN_FAILED);
                       // [END_EXCLUDE]
                   }
               }
           });
          }
   ```

All code taken from firebase doc....

Comment: I did it yesterday and working fine. Do you get any error?